# JPA inject where clause in queries

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I need help with JPA. I need to add dynamic subquery to the where clause in all my queries. Is there any way I can tap-in just before the query is executed and modify it. I want to create AOP-like feature to add some checks inside the queries.

Thanks!

Comment: is there any thing you've tried so far?

Comment: Well, what i did was use the criteria api, created my class that adds the subquery and returns it to the service i want to use it in. Then in the service i add the other predicates. I don't like this option because i don't want for the service to assume that the query contains anything else but what it sets inside the where clause.

Besides, I want to make it transparent for any future services...